# cannot download packages with chocolatey on azure vm due to ssl error

Tags: azure, ssl, virtual-machine

cannot download any packages with chocolotey
using vm azure with windows server 2019
i had this error:

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

i try to download choco packages

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

Install chocolatey and after installing, you can verify it:

```
choco
```

[image]

I installed the packages from chocolatey in 2019 windows server like below:

```
chocolatey install tcps
```

[image]

Based on your error, `community.chocolatey.org` now requires TLS 1.2 at a minimum.

We can also see the same thing in the console, when we run the command to install the chocolatey package.

[image]

The owner must verify the version of TLS which using currently, and also failure could be the website you are trying to download from has disabled the support for TLS 1.2 which PS uses by default.

To know more in detail, **refer** below links:

[Chocolatey Software | Installing Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install#install-step2)

[Chocolatey Software Docs | Troubleshooting](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting)